# Why does this request handler function block other requests?

Tags: node.js

I have the following request handlers which I think they should be non-blocking but they aren't. If I send a request for upload, it blocks other requests even though it is running a child_process. What am I doing wrong?

```
var exec = require("child_process").exec;
function upload(response) {
    console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ": Request handler 'upload' was called.");

    exec("echo 'Hello Upload'", function (error, stdout, stderr) {

        function sleep(milliSeconds) {
            var startTime = new Date().getTime();
            while (new Date().getTime() < startTime + milliSeconds);
        }

        sleep(10000);

        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        response.write(stdout);
        response.end();

        console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ":" + stdout);
    });
    console.log(new Date().toISOString() + ": Request 'upload' dispatched.");
}
```

Here's the log:

```
2014-03-03T18:19:33.615Z: Request handler 'upload' was called.
2014-03-03T18:19:33.631Z: Request 'upload' dispatched.
2014-03-03T18:19:43.641Z:'Hello Upload'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're sleeping in the callback, not the subprocess;

```
exec("echo 'Hello Upload'", function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    ...
    sleep(10000);
```

...will only run `echo 'Hello Upload'` in a subprocess, and when the echo is finished it will terminate the process and call back to sleep on the event thread. This will block the event loop and cause your entire program to block.

Comment: Thanks Joachim. You're right. That makes perfect sense. I was trying to figure out if there is a way to do a long running process in node.js without blocking. Of course it was a misguided attempt but is there a way to do that other than writing it in java and running it in a child process?

Comment: @tyrion Do you mean that you're doing things that take a great deal of CPU that you want to upload? As long as they're doing I/O (such as uploads you're talking about), I can't really see a reason to offload.

Answer (score 0):

My answer to your question in the comment is longer than 50 characters so, I'm putting it in an answer which is not far from the truth.

Never mind the function name. This was from an example in Manuel Kiessling's "Node.js Beginner" Book that I was playing around with. This is not for a real application. I'm just trying to learn the non-blocking features of Node.js. I got confused about the callback function and put the busy loop in there to simulate a CPU intensive application.

As I understand now, there is no way to dispatch a CPU intensive function to a thread. You either have to run it in Node.js's own event loop (and block everything) or in a separate child_process as a Java or native app and run it non-blocking in exec(). The only non-blocking feature that Node.js DOES provide is I/O. Is this a fair understanding?